# What is the use of "apiVersion" property in resource section (resources array) of azure resource manager template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-resources), it is mentioned that `apiVersion` property should be used to specify the REST API version of the resource.

However, in this [101-automation-configuration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-automation-configuration/azuredeploy.json) template,
api version mentioned here for resource type `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` is  `2018-02-01`.

[image]

If we look at the available versions for `Microsoft.Resources/deployments`, we see following values: 
`2017-08-01,2017-06-01,2017-05-10,2017-05-01,2017-03-01,2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview`. I am not sure from where this `2018-02-01` version is coming.

The api version `2018-02-01` is used in nested templates of this template.
(Template link is given in 'templateLink' property).

So, what does api version signifies in this template resource?

Comment: Maybe they have not updated the list of API versions yet? The parameter is always required since an ARM template is basically transformed into a series of requests against the ARM API, which requires you to specify which version of the API you are using. That would affect the properties available.

Comment: We are using '2017-05-10' api version to list the available api versions for type 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments' (as mentioned in the azure rest api documentation). If we use any invalid api version to deploy this template, it shows 'ApiVersion' property is invalid error.

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically arm templates just describe how and which rest api calls you want to perform. api version is appended to the path of the call, so the resource provider can know which version are you working against.

this particular version is either a typo or internal only something. might be a regional thing. as far as I know there are internal use only regions.

edit: I've assumed you checked the api versions, but I clearly see the api version available:

```
(Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.Resources').ResourceTypes | 
    ? resourcetypename -eq deployments | ft resourcetypename, apiversions

ResourceTypeName ApiVersions
---------------- -----------
deployments      {2018-02-01, 2018-01-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-06-01...}
```

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41. When we tried the same command on friday we were not getting this updated versions list. May be now they have updated the api versions list so without any change in the same command, we can see the updated api versions list.